# Using begininvoke/endinvoke efficiently

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using the below code to perform asynchronous operations using multithreading. As you can see here, in the for loop, n number of threads are created. 
How to ensure that resources gets properly used. Iam using .net 3.5 framework.

The operation is simple one so each thread will not be blocking for a long time. But as the value of n may be very huge, what i am trying to achieve here is efficient resource utilization. 
Any suggestions would be of great help.

In Main:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
....
    PerformAsyncFunction(id);

}
```

---

```
public delegate bool MyDelegate(int id); 


public bool PerformAsyncFunction(id)
{
    Mydelegate del = new Mydelegate(Myfunction);
    AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(MyCallback); 
    IAsyncResult ar = del.BeginInvoke(id, cb, null); 
}


public bool MyCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
try
{ 
    Mydelegate del = (Mydelegate )((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate; try { 
    bool result = del.EndInvoke(ar); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    ....
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a parallel loop instead. It will use up threads based on the system capabilities. The loop blocks until it finishes but you shouldn't be affected by this since it's during a web request (and you want all work to be finished before the response is flushed).

```
var workCollection = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToList();
ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<bool>();

Parallel.ForEach(workCollection, id => {
  results.Add(id, PerformWork(id));
  //in PerformWork you need to call Myfunction (or just replace it with MyfFunction, or the work it does).
});

//now you can update the database with what's in results
foreach(var result in results)
{
  UpdateDatabase(result.Key, result.Value); //<-- Key is id, while Value is the boolean result
}
```

About the database update, I'd send it all in one round trip. You can look into ADO.NET structured parameters on how to do this.

More on [parallel for each here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The source collection is partitioned and the work is scheduled on
>   multiple threads based on the system environment. The more processors
>   on the system, the faster the parallel method runs.

Comment: In the callback method, i perform database update which is basically updating of the bool status returned by the endinvoke.

Comment: can you pl point the flaws in the begininvoke/endinvoke code above. How is it different from using Parallel For loop.

Comment: @khcha22: You asked for efficient resource utilization. Parallel for each gives you that. With begin/endinvoke you'd have to do that yourself by counting the processors and corest, maybe checking the system load at that moment, etc, etc. There could be several factors that influence the optimal number of threads you can start at one moment.

Comment: But, however async delegate uses Threadpool? So threads will be properly used. Am i right?

Comment: Actually, the loop will be running in a batch with n = 50. The main function will wait untill the 50 operations are done. only then the loop will again be run.

Comment: @khcha22: Async delegates are executed on the TP, but the thread pool will start to throttle them as soon as it hits capacity. So, if you still want to use your original approach, at least consider this. Anyway, you also get cleaner/less code with a parallel loop.